# How to parse JSON string from php which displays correctly in Android Studio console but cant be parsed due to extra hidden things?

Tags: android

[Code in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNkko.jpg)

The string returned by php is stored in result. If I print the result in console, it shows the correct json contents. But THe JSONObject cant parse it. If I copy and paste the json content from log and use escape sequence for '"', the program works as intended. Some said that I need to do utf without bom. I converted it to that from notepad ++. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to S.O, you should see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And show your code .

Comment: Please show your code and the response that you’re trying to parse, as well as any stackTrack exceptions that get thrown :)

Comment: sorry...If you click on the description, you can see the code and there is error inlogcat. there you can see object returned. so